# Mocking stdlib function in pytest fixture

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am trying to mock `random.shuffle` so I get predictable results from some tests. However, I am not able to setup the mock.

The call to `random.shuffle` is located in a function defined in the top `__init__.py` file of my application. I imported `random` and use `random.shuffle`. I am trying to mock it in a fixture in my application. I rely on [pytest-mock](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock) to do the mock.

I tried: `mock.patch('aot.random')`, `mock.patch('aot.random.shuffle')`, `mock.patch('random')` and `mock.patch('random.shuffle')` without success. I tried to add the `side_effect` argument but it had no effect.

I also tried to use `from random import shuffle` and the `mock.patch` calls listed below.

I also tried to create a shuffle function in `aot.utils.__init__.py` and mock it with `mock.patch('aot.shuffle')` and `mock.patch('aot.utils.shuffle')` in my test (after importing it in the module of course)

What I find strange is that I am able to mock other classes or function correctly.

Is there a way to do this?

Additionnal information:

- The full code of the application is here: https://bitbucket.org/arenaoftitans/arena-of-titans-api/src/a60821c4f71e?at=blizzard
- The `random.shuffle` function is use [here](https://bitbucket.org/arenaoftitans/arena-of-titans-api/src/a60821c4f71ef6b839290ca2c65520c88d18c22c/aot/__init__.py?at=blizzard&fileviewer=file-view-default#__init__.py-147)
- The ineffective mock is [here](https://bitbucket.org/arenaoftitans/arena-of-titans-api/src/a60821c4f71ef6b839290ca2c65520c88d18c22c/aot/test/__init__.py?at=blizzard&fileviewer=file-view-default#__init__.py-72)

Comment: Another way to get predictable values from `random` is to do `random._inst.seed(<constant value>)`, which will ensure that `random.shuffle()` always gives the same value (If done in the same order)

Comment: Where is the `mock` fixture being defined for this code?: `def player(mock, board, deck):
    mock.patch('aot.random')`. For what it's worth I've only ever seen `mock.patch()` used as a context manager or decorator, perhaps that will perform the mocking correctly.

Comment: The `mock` fixture comes from the [pytest-mock](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock) plugin. I'll try to see if standard `unittest.mock` will od the trick.

Comment: Sadly, standard mock doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

To get idempotent results from functions in `random`, one sets a `seed`.

```
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5926, Jul 16 2017, 20:11:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin

import random

lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']

random.seed(111)

for i in range(5):
    random.shuffle(lst)
    print(lst)

['c', 'b', 'a']
['a', 'c', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['b', 'a', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']

lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']

random.seed(111)
for i in range(5):
    random.shuffle(lst)
    print(lst)

['c', 'b', 'a']
['a', 'c', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['b', 'a', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: While testing your solution I found out my problem: I was using the function that rely on `random.shuffle` in another fixture and I forgot to use `mock.patch` in it. Silly me. Anyway, thanks for your help!